# How can I make an iPhone or iPad app that installs on the phone but accesses data from a website?

Tags: iphone, ipad, 3d, viewer

I would like to make an iPhone or iPad app for my company that is a 3d model viewer.  Through much discussion with others, I have realized that it would be best if the customers use the app on their phone and log into it with their username and password.  This will allow them to access the 3d models they are allowed to access.  It cannot use webGL for the 3d viewing since ipad and iphone don't support webgl.

The reason I haven't used model viewers that are currently in the app store is because i want it to be specific to my company and not just some random app that we have the customers download.  We want it to be our company app.

Can anyone offer suggestions by way of tutorials or links that will show me how to accomplish this?  I would very much appreciate it!

To summarize: I need information that will help me learn how to make an app for iPhone or iPad that will have an interface on the device itself but retrieve (and allow for viewing) 3d models from our website, specific to a user based on their log in credentials.

Comment: What you're looking for is "web services."

Comment: cool, this helps with part of it... do you know where to find information on how to make a web based model viewer that will work on iphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great place to start is [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).  This site has a great list of tutorials to help you on your path to creating what you're looking for.

Basically, it's going to take some work and you're going to have to start from the ground up if you don't have any experience with iOS.  Ray's site has a wealth of information.

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1) will help you start a basic app.

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12) article talks about creating an app with a web service backend.

As for displaying 3D information, that's going to take a bit more work.  The site has an [OpenGL EL](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial) series.  I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Rogers!  I'm glad you saw this and answered for me before the topic was closed.  This helps me tremendously.  I do not understand why my question was closed.  I have asked so many questions on this site and so far you are one of the few people that has actually tried to help me as opposed to just trying to close my question.  Again, Thank you!

Comment: @zachboy82: It's nothing personal, but we prefer to keep the site more tightly focused than your average, run-of-the-mill forum.  That's why Stack Overflow is more useful, and why you come here instead of those other forums.  Keep learning!

Comment: Can you send me somewhere or explain to me how I can ask better questions?  I have read the guidelines and I don't really understand how my question is considered to be outside them.

Comment: @zachboy82 you could try looking through the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)